# Why is my background image not showing?

Tags: html, css

I have a button on my page that I'd like to apply a background image to.

When I have the following code, it doesn't apply. Can anyone explain why?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/p7octep1/

```css
.form-file-upload .close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  right: -13px;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 0;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/26x26) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-file-upload">
  <button type="button" class="close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: why you use `position: absolute;` and `top and right` with `-13px`

Comment: Your above code is working, just use `position:relative;` to immediate parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've hidden your button with `top:-13px`, `right:-13px` and `position:absolute` properties. Position your button at the left top corner to see that background is applied:

```css
.form-file-upload .close {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
  z-index: 3;
  border: 0;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/26x26") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-file-upload">

  <button type="button" class="close"></button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this , you need to set `position:relative;` to the parent div

```css
.form-file-upload {
   position:relative;
}
.form-file-upload .close {
   display:block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   width: 26px;
   height: 26px;
   font-size: 18px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 26px;
   z-index: 3;
   border: 0;
   background: url(http://placehold.it/26x26) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-file-upload">
   <button type="button" class="close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to implement this code here: https://jsfiddle.net/p7octep1/6/ Any reason why it still doesn't display?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk close button showing the right side because we set `right:0` to `.close` class, anyway you got the answer thanks for your reivew

Answer (score 1):

```css
.form-file-upload .close {
    float: right;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 0;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/26x26) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-file-upload">

<button type="button" class="close"></button>

</div>
```

Your button works fine , but due to position it not showing

```
top: -13px;
right: -13px;
```

You can use

```
float: right;
```

if you want in right side.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing in the top right corner in your fiddle.

You are using `top: -13px;` and `right: -13px;`. If your want the button to show up in the top right corner you should set those to `0`.

top:

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies the distance between the element's top edge and the top edge of its containing block.
>   [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/top)

right:

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the right property specifies the distance between the element's right edge and the right edge of its containing block.
>   [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/right)

so using `-13px` will render it half of screen for the `top` rule and will overflow to the right of the screen for the `right` rule

Answer (score 0):

it shows on top & right~ not hidden :)
normally, when set 
`position: absolute`, 
`left & top will always be set`
absolute position will check its first relative (or absolute) parent;
if add

```
 .form-file-upload {
  position: relative;
}
```

you'll hava some change~